# How to remove ACCOUNT from top right of page?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

How to remove ACCOUNT from top right of page?

I want to remove it only from the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it: create or edit your theme’s `local.xml` file under `layout` like this:

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

The main advantage here is that you don’t have to override the default `customer.xml` layout file, making upgrades much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your theme layout folder:-

> app/design/frontend/package_name/your_theme/layout

Edit customer.xml and comment action tag like below:

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
         <!-- <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>-->
     </reference>
</default>
```